# What is causing the navigation timeout in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright-test

Here is an example trace:

https://trace.playwright.dev/?trace=https://playwright-tests.contra.dev/47d6a480-70c0-4b30-8d96-cd765c8a4b33.zip

All it says:

> Call proxy.goto
>
> navigating to "https://web-app-c445f297.contra.dev/", waiting until "load"
>
> Timeout 30000ms exceeded.

The actual code initiating navigation is:

```
await page.goto('/');
```

However, as far as I can tell, there are no errors, etc.

Network tab is empty.

[image]

The same test usually works, but it fails at random times.

How do I identify and fix the underlying cause?